# faster algorithm or technique for building sparse arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix-building problem.  To build the matrix (for a 3rd party package), I need to do it row-by-row by passing a double[] array to the 3rd-party object.  Here's my problem:  I have a list of objects that represent paths on a graph.  Each object is a path with a 'source' property (string) and a 'destination' property (also string).  I need to build a 1-dimensional array where all the elements are 0 *except* where the source property is equal to a given name.  The given name will occur multiple times in the path list.  Here's my function for building the sparse array:

```
    static double[] GetNodeSrcRow3(string nodeName)
    {
        double[] r = new double[cpaths.Count ];
        for (int i = 1; i < cpaths.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cpaths[i].src == nodeName) r[i] = 1;
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Now I need to call this function about 200k times with different names.  The function itself takes between 0.05 and 0.1 seconds (timed with Stopwatch).  As you can imagine, if we take the best possible case of 0.05 seconds * 200k calls = 10,000 seconds = 2.7 hours which is too long.  The object 'cpaths' contains about 200k objects.

Can someone think of a way to accomplish this in a faster way?

Comment: what is type of the cpaths? is it normal list?

Comment: This looks like an ideal job for the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library).

Comment: I reckon its the looping 200K * 200K that is killing it. Can you do it in 1 pass? ie make a double[][] and use soem function of nodeName for hte new index - then you only need to loop once.

Comment: If the 3rd party library requires a `double[]` he probably can't get away with using a different data-type.

Comment: The `ArraySegment<T>` class *might* be useful to avoid the extra allocations.  Just throwing it out there.

Comment: @bradley yes but then you just iterate through the result and pass each 'row' to the 3rd party lib. This way it is 2 loops of 200K instead of 200K. Howerver, it depends on being able to map a nodeName to an index in some way (e.g. make a disctionary up front) so maybe 3 loops.

Comment: cpaths is a normal List object.  I'll try using a dictionary.  I have to return a double[] type array, so no other data type is usable on return.

Comment: Have you run any performance profiling to find where the actual hot-spots are?  It would help with targeting optimizations.

Comment: Try converting `cpaths` into a dictionary. You're doing a full walk of `cpaths` which can't be good for performance... doing indexed checks will definitely reduce the time spent in the function.

Comment: You say (1) there are 200K distinct names, (2) there are 200K nodes on the path, and (3) each name occurs possibly multiple times on the path.  By the pigeonhole principle we see that **the typical case is that each name occurs only a tiny number of times**.  But you do 200K **linear searches** to find the *tiny number* of indices. Is this analysis correct? Or is it possible that there is one name that is in 199K of the nodes, and most of the remaining 199999 names occur not at all in the remaining 1000 nodes?  **This matters**.

Comment: Doing a linear search of the node list is killing you, but knowing what is the efficient data structure to use that is better strongly depends on the actual number of distinct names, and whether they can appear zero times, whether they appear a small positive number of times, or whether they can appear many times on the node list.

Comment: @EricLippert - You are right, the name will only occur about 500 times in the list of 200k items.  You're right that linear search is killing it.  I'm trying the code using dictionaries that was posted below.  Looks much faster, but still running...

Comment: Wait -- you say you're doing this call 200K times, the node list is 200K long, and that each name appears 500 times, but that's impossible unless either (1) the names are duplicated, and there are only about 400 names, not 200K names, or (2) a common case is that the name is not found. Both afford you additional optimizations. But here is a key question:  **Does the library that you pass the vector to modify the vector**?  If it does not, then you can use a variety of memoization techniques to increase speed and massively decrease allocation cost.

Comment: @EricLippert I should have been more clear, the cpaths list is 200k long.  it contains *paths*, e.g. a source and a destination combination.  There are approximately 500 unique sources and 500 unique destinations.  I just realized that I don't need to do 200k checks, just the 500 + 500.  That should help a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see the rest of your code, but I suspect most of the time is spent allocating and garbage collecting all the arrays.  Assuming the size of `cpaths` doesn't change, you can reuse the same array.

```
private static double[] NodeSourceRow == null;
private static List<int> LastSetIndices = new List<int>();

static double[] GetNodeSrcRow3(string nodeName) {
    // create new array *only* on the first call
    NodeSourceRow = NodeSourceRow ?? new double[cpaths.Count];

    // reset all elements to 0
    foreach(int i in LastSetIndices) NodeSourceRow[i] = 0;
    LastSetIndices.Clear();

    // set the 1s
    for (int i = 1; i < cpaths.Count; i++) {
        if (cpaths[i].src == nodeName) {
            NodeSourceRow[i] = 1;
            LastSetIndices.Add(i);
        }
    }

    // tada!!
    return NodeSourceRow;
}
```

One drawback potential drawback would be if you need all the arrays to used at the same time, they will always have identical contents.  But if you only use one at a time, this should be much faster.

Comment: No, I need to keep each array preserved with their individual unique contents.  Thanks though, great idea.

Comment: Accepted!  Got it down to 40 seconds through using the dictionaries, plus figuring out that I could reduce the number of calls dramatically once I have already called a given name.

Comment: good idea on reusing same allocated memory. though OP has to be careful not storing these references somewhere, else weird stuff happens :)

Answer (score 4):

if cpaths is normal list then that's not suitable for your case. you need a dictionary of `src` to list of indexes. like `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

then you can fill sparse array with random access. I would also suggest you to use Sparse list implementation for efficient memory usage rather than using memory inefficient `double[]`. a good implementation is [SparseAList](http://core.loyc.net/collections/alists-part3.html). (written by David Piepgrass)

Before generating your sparse lists, you should convert your `cpaths` list into a suitable dictionary, this step may take a little long (up to few seconds), but after that you will generate your sparse lists super fast.

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> _dictionary;

public static void CacheIndexes()
{
    _dictionary = cpaths.Select((x, i) => new { index = i, value = x })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.value.src)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(a => a.index).ToList());
}
```

you should call `CacheIndexes` before starting to generate your sparse arrays.

```
public static double[] GetNodeSrcRow3(string nodeName)
{
    double[] r = new double[cpaths.Count];
    List<int> indexes;
    if(!_dictionary.TryGetValue(nodeName, out indexes)) return r;

    foreach(var index in indexes) r[index] = 1;

    return r;
}
```

---

Note that if you use `SparseAList` it will occupy very small space. for example if double array is `10K` length and has only one index set in it, with `SparseAList` you will have virtually `10K` items, but in fact there is only one item stored in memory. its not hard to use that collection, I suggest you to give it a try.

same code using `SparseAList`

```
public static SparseAList<double> GetNodeSrcRow3(string nodeName)
{
    SparseAList<double> r = new SparseAList<double>();

    r.InsertSpace(0, cpaths.Count); // allocates zero memory.

    List<int> indexes;
    if(!_dictionary.TryGetValue(nodeName, out indexes)) return r;

    foreach(var index in indexes) r[index] = 1;

    return r;
}
```

Comment: I'm running this now, the first suggestion, it is significantly faster, looks like about 10x faster.  I can't use SparseAList because the 3rd party tool requires a double[], so I'd still have to convert.  

Very good idea, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of multi-threading using the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7)'s [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7) method.

```
static double[] GetNodeSrcRow3(string nodeName)
{
    double[] r = new double[cpaths.Count];
    Parallel.For(1, cpaths.Count, (i, state) =>
        {
            if (cpaths[i].src == nodeName) r[i] = 1;
        });
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of improvement required here... Suppose you have 32 cores, all idle... You'll cut 2.7 hours to ~5-6 minutes - not enough.

Comment: I dunno, that sounds like a fantastic improvement to me.  I would even be happy if this *only* sped it up 10x.

Comment: mix of my answer with parallel would be even much faster. OP could distribute `GetNodeSrcRow3` job into 4 cores running in parallel. since OP is calling this function `200k`, he would instead call it `50k` times per core.

Answer (score -1):

Fantastic Answers!

If I may add some, to the already great examples:

```
System.Numerics.Tensors.SparseTensor<double> GetNodeSrcRow3(string text)
{

    // A quick NuGet System.Numerics.Tensors Install:
    System.Numerics.Tensors.SparseTensor<double> SparseTensor = new System.Numerics.Tensors.SparseTensor<double>(new int[] { cpaths.Count }, true, 1);

    Parallel.For(1, cpaths.Count, (i, state) =>
    {
        if (cpaths[i].src == nodeName) SparseTensor[i] = 1.0D;
    });

    return SparseTensor;
}
```

System.Numerics is optimised hugely, also uses hardware acceleration. It is also Threadsafe. At least from what I have read about it.

For Speed and scalability, a small bit of code that could make all the difference.